# Sapper - imported scss styles disappear

Tags: sass, svelte, rollup, sapper

I have a strange problem which may be related toe tree-shaking. I build a *sapper* app and in my *rollup* config, I use the [svelte-preprocess package](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) and configure it like this:

```
const preprocessOptions = {
  scss: {
    data: `@import '${join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/main.scss")}';`,
    includePaths: ["node_modules", "src"],
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: [
      require("autoprefixer"),
      require("cssnano")({
        preset: "default",
      }),
    ],
    minimize: !isDevelopment,
    sourceMap: isDevelopment,
  },
};
```

Via the `scss` plugin I copy the global stylesheet *main.scss*. All of the styles out of it seem to get applied, except for the styles of the `body`. Somehow these get ignored, because when I check the body styles in the dev console, it is empty. Can't you access the body in Sapper or is there maybe a special way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with Sapper the body is part of the template.html file.  That means there's no component with a body element.  Svelte will remove styles that are not used in your component unless they are explicitly marked as `global`.  The [global preprocessor](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#global-rule) can help with this.  I think in your case I would just get the bundler to create a separate css file for the template.html and include it explicitly like the global.css:

```
...
%sapper.base%

<link rel='stylesheet' href='global.css'>
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As there are only a few styles, I moved them directly into a style tag in the template. I think using an extra stylesheet or the global preprocessor might be overkill in that case.